# SumUP Checkout with Widget Fails with Public Key and Secret Key

Tags: php, e-commerce, sumup-payments

After several hours of trying to make sense of SumUps online checkout widget I am pulling my hair out. (Stripe and Pay Pal are so much simpler but the client wants to use SumUp).
I am using this code but it keeps returning "Response error: Client error" returned.

```
include 'vendor/autoload.php';

try {
  $sumup = new \SumUp\SumUp([
  'app_id' => 'cc_classic_*****************',
  'app_secret' => 'sup_sk_*****************',
  ]);
  $checkoutService = $sumup->getCheckoutService();
  $checkoutResponse = $checkoutService->create($amount, $currency, $checkoutRef, $payToEmail);
  $checkoutId = $checkoutResponse->getBody()->id;
//  pass the $chekoutId to the front-end to be processed
} catch (\SumUp\Exceptions\SumUpAuthenticationException $e) {
  echo 'Authentication error: ' . $e->getMessage();
} catch (\SumUp\Exceptions\SumUpResponseException $e) {
  echo 'Response error: ' . $e->getMessage();
} catch(\SumUp\Exceptions\SumUpSDKException $e) {
  echo 'SumUp SDK error: ' . $e->getMessage();
}

<div id="sumup-card"></div>
<script
  type="text/javascript"
  src="https://gateway.sumup.com/gateway/ecom/card/v2/sdk.js"
></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  SumUpCard.mount({
    id: 'sumup-card',
    currency: 'GBP',
    locale: 'UK',
    amount: '<?php echo $price; ?>',
    email: '<?php echo $email?>',
    checkout_reference: '<?php echo $prod_code; ?>', 
    showEmail: true,
    showFooter: true,
    showAmount: true,
    checkoutId: '2ceffb63-cbbe-4227-87cf-0409dd191a98',
    onResponse: function (type, body) {
      console.log('Type', type);
      console.log('Body', body);
    },
  });
</script>
```

I need to get **$checkoutId** to add to the javascript **checkoutId** variable.

The Test account is fine according to the email I received from SumUp support.
Sumup is poorly documented with this and there are few developers discussing this ecommerce solution.
Any help with this will be appreciated. I used Composer to install the SDK. I thank all of you in advance.

Comment: `$checkoutResponse = $checkoutService->create($amount, $currency, $checkoutRef, $payToEmail);` - so where are any of those variables you are passing as parameters there, supposed to come from? That the included autoloader script leads to their creation, is unlikely, I suppose, so is there any more code before this ...?

Comment: Yes. The variables are loaded from previous page after submitting item and shipping details.

Comment: And you have _verified_ that they all contains the values you think they should? (You're using `$amount` up there, but then further down in theJS part, it's `amount: '<?php echo $price; ?>',` - not sure if both actually exist, or if you maybe confused your variable names in one of those places.)

Comment: Yes. $price exists as it shows in the submit button. The variables are loaded from previous page after submitting item and shipping details. 'app_id' and 'app_secret' seem to be incorrect. But they are freshly created. I have just receievd an email from the SumUp team and they have sent me a link to  https://github.com/sumup/sumup-ecom-php-sdk. I dont know where **code** varibale is supposed to be taken from. ```$sumup = new \SumUp\SumUp([
      'app_id'     => PUBLIC_KEY,
      'app_secret' => SECRET_KEY,
      'code'       => AUTH_CODE
  ]);```

Comment: You need to send the user to the authorization URL, and when they get redirected back from there, the `code` will be appended in the URL. https://developer.sumup.com/online-payments/introduction/authorization#authorization-code-flow

Comment: I have had to use Stripe to accomplish the task. I still want to to know how to get the authorization code to make SumUp  Payment Widget  work using the PHP SDK. For the life of me nothing I try works. I end up with Response error: Client error. Is there any working basic code sample to copy from or learn from?